# Ploteando un obj

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, float

Tengo un df con fechas y valores, ambos como objetos, claramente al plotearlos plt no me va a plotear obj, pero al querer convertir el obj en float, todos los datos se convierten en Nan, y en el mejor de los casos me dice que

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' $693,32'**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("Historico.csv")
df

df.columns = ["Fecha","TTRM"]
df

df = df.TTRM.astype("float")
```

Comment: Buen día, necesitas "limpiar" la columna ya que claramente es un `string`, necesitas quitar los símbolos `$` y convertir las comas a puntos.